# Potted Japanese Pieris not doing well -need to repot it -any advice?

Tags: shrubs, repotting

The plant is like 5 years old and it did not seem to enjoy the in ground planting or the place where it was planted (full sun in the afternoon -this is in Toronto-5a)

Last year I moved the plant to the pot you see and the situation worsened.
After seeing what is happening I decided to do some reading and I am learning that it likes acidic wet soil, drained after deeply watered.

Right now I am set to go buy a bag of peat moss and one of these https://www.homedepot.ca/product/miracle-gro-water-soluble-evergreen-acid-loving-plant-food-28-10-10-500-g/1001200911  and try to repot it in a larger barrel planter as seen below (I am removing that frozen to death euonimus)

Am I doing the right thing here ? Do I need to mix the peat moss with some soil?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Some plants don't mind other plants in their pot, some don